# will the difference between a .001 cap and a .0015 cap matter?

Tags: circuits

I am doing a build for a guitar stomp box from this website and was wondering if a .0015 capacitor could be used instead of a .001 capacitor. The build i got from https://www.tonefiend.com//wp-content/uploads/DIY-Club-Project-2-v02.pdf and im using version 3 for the build

Comment: and the units are? And we don't like clicking the links.

Comment: Please adopt engineering prefixes.

Comment: .001 of what? potato?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're talking about the indicated capacitor:

[image]

It will make some difference to the frequency response (let lower frequencies through with the tone pot set to maximum resistance (CCW)).

If you are blessed with a surfeit of 0.0015uF capacitors you can hack the correct value by placing two in parallel and then adding another in series with that parallel pair. Total is 1/(1/0.003 + 1/0.0015) = 0.001uF.

Answer (score 1):

It will in designing filters, as the capacitance affects the filter's pole location. In power filter applications, probably not much of a difference. Most caps have more than 5% tolerance. If you're really worried about it, buy a bunch, measure them and select the closest matched cap to the value you need.